# How pipe the output of for loop into another variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
for {for loop assertion }:
    if (a) > 0 and b > 0:
        print('same')
    elif (a) < 0 and b < 0:
        print('same')
    else:
        print('different')
```

This produces a list like this:

```
different
different
same
different
same
different
same
different
different
same
different
different
different
different
different
same
```

What I want to do is save this to another variable. Could you please advise how I can accomplish that?

Comment: Do you know how to add ("append") one value to a list?

Comment: While what you want to do literally is possible, is there a reason you're using `print`? You could just directly `append` into a list instead.

Comment: You haven't created a list at all. You've simply printed stuff the the standard output device. You need to learn to use data structures like `list` objects and `dict` objects to organize your code

Comment: The second `if` should be an `elif`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @VPfB you don't have to use elifs over ifs you could have 7 if statements and that would still be fine

Comment: @Theshape If `a = b = 1`, then the output is `same` and also `different`. Is that still fine?

Comment: Yes I agree in this instance you may need t use elif but in some other codes/functions you don't  **need** it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work, if not tell me why:

```
lst = []
for {for loop assertion }:
        if (a) > 0 and b > 0:
            lst += ["same"]
        if (a) < 0 and b < 0:
            lst += ["same"]
        else:
            lst += ["different"]
```

or you could do:

```
    lst = []
    for {for loop assertion }:
            if (a) > 0 and b > 0:
                lst.append("same")
            if (a) < 0 and b < 0:
                lst.append("same")
            else:
                lst.append("different")
```

Comment: And also, not needed but if it is a working answer you should click the check mark, so other users when they see it, they will find a working answer.

Comment: kk :) @ZaphodBeeblebrox

Comment: Can only close it once after 10 mins

Comment: btw Zaphod this question isn't exactly closed

Comment: that doesnt mean its closed

Comment: it just means that you have accepted a right answer

Comment: closing it means that no more answers will be accepted